# Why is this diamond class inheritance output not what I expect?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {// base class
private:
    int data;
public:
    A(int data = 0) 
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
    void show() 
    {
        cout << data << endl;
        return;
    }
};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
    B(int data = 0) :
        A(data) {
    }
};

class C : virtual public A {
public:
    C(int data = 0) :
        A(data) {
    }
};

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    D(int dataB = 0, int dataC = 0) :
        B(dataB),
        C(dataC) {
    }
};

int main() {
    D d(1, 2);
    d.B::show();
    d.C::show();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is the diamond class inheritance diagram. The base class is A. I use virtual inheritance to avoid the diamond problem. But why is the output of this program **0,0**, not **1,2** as I expect?

`B`'s constructor is passed `data=1`, and in its initializer list it calls `A` with `data`.  `C`'s constructor similar is passed `data=2` and its initializer list it calls `A` with `data`.

We then ask the `B` and `C` subobjects to `show` their value.  And we get `0` `0` not `1` `2` as I expect.

Comment: You can have 1,2 very easily -just make that inheritance NOT virtual :) Then you'll have TWO copies of A.

Comment: Anyway the `this->` is odd. In modern C++ you can write `A(int data = 0): data(data) {}`, 'constructor initialization list', which is cleaner, and allows you to have constant members.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have `virtual` inheritance, the `virtual` base class is initialized by the constructor of the most derived class.

```
D(int dataB = 0, int dataC = 0) :
    B(dataB),
    C(dataC) {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
D(int dataB = 0, int dataC = 0) :
    A(),
    B(dataB),
    C(dataC) {}
```

which is, in your case, the same as

```
D(int dataB = 0, int dataC = 0) :
    A(0),
    B(dataB),
    C(dataC) {}
```

Unless you construct an instance of `B`,

```
B(int data = 0) :
    A(data) {
}
```

is the same as

```
B(int data = 0) {}
```

with no code to initialize `A` since `A` is already initialized in the constructor of `D`.

Same thing applies to the implementation of `C::C(int data)`.

That explains the output you are seeing.

Answer (score 21):

When you have this scheme with virtual inheritance, it is up to the most derived class in the hierarchy (in this case `D`) to call the constructor of the common base (`A`)<sup>1,2</sup>.

Since your constructor for `A` has a default parameter `data = 0`, it can be used as a default constructor. And this is what's happening, the common `A` sub-object gets default constructed, since you omitted it from `D`'s member initialization list.

If you remove the default value for `data`, you'll get a nice compiler error for emphasis:

```
A(int data) 
{
    this->data = data;
}
```

[On g++ it results with](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e101c619e81434cb):

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'D::D(int, int)':
main.cpp:37:16: error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'
         C(dataC) {
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Remember that with virtual inheritance there is only **one** sub-object of type `A`. And both the `B` and `C` sub-objects refer to it. It is impossible for your calls to `show` to print different things, since they access *the same* data. That is why it's up to the most derived class, so there is no ambiguity.

[[class.mi/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mi#4)

> A base class specifier that does not contain the keyword virtual specifies a non-virtual base class. A base class specifier that contains the keyword virtual specifies a virtual base class. For each distinct occurrence of a non-virtual base class in the class lattice of the most derived class, the most derived object shall contain a corresponding distinct base class subobject of that type. **For each distinct base class that is specified virtual, the most derived object shall contain a single base class subobject of that type.**

[[class.base.init/13.1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13)

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - First, **and only for the constructor of the most derived class, virtual base classes are initialized** in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
> - ...

<sup>2</sup> So if you want to construct `A` with specific data you'd define `D::D()` like this instead:

```
D(int dataA = 0) :
  A(dataA) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the concept of `virtual` inheritance and the 'diamond problem'. With `virtual` inheritance, you create a diamond inheritance pattern, but from your post, it appears that you want to avoid that and instead have two bases `A`, one from `B` and another from `C`. To obtain that, simply avoid virtual inheritance in `B` and `C`, when your code will write `1 2`.

Incidently, if only `B` has `virtual` inheritance from `A` but `C` conventional inheritance from `A`, then `D` will have two bases `A`, but that from `B` is again default initialised (as explained in the other answers).